# Ionic 3 - Can't open videos in an iOS phone

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to figure out why videos aren't being executed when I'm running my app on an iPhone or similar. However, it's possible to execute when I'm running it on Android. Is it a problem with Cordova? Has anyone faced the same problem? Thanks

TS:

```
export class PlayerVideoPage {
  public source: String = '';
  public title: String = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public orientation: OrientationService) {
    this.source = navParams.get('url');
    this.title = navParams.get('title');

    this.orientation.unlock()
  }

   dismiss() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
    this.orientation.lock()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.orientation.lock();
  }

  loadVideo() {
      return './assets/learn/videos/' + this.source;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h4 text-center>{{title}}</h4>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <video controls playsinline>
        <source [src]="loadVideo()"
            type='video/mp4;'/>
      </video>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="button-controls">
      <button ion-button icon-only round (click)="dismiss()">
         <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

iOS:
[image: Screenshot1]

Android:
[image]

Comment: IOS does not read all codecs that Android reads. I suggest you test with a video that is saved on ios.

Comment: It actualy uses a `H264 mpeg 4` video codec, I'm afraid this isn't the problem :/

Comment: Can you show the `code` related to this implementation?

Comment: @Sampath sorry I had forgotten to add the implementation, so I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the below line to the `config.xml`:

*config.xml*

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```